# Visual indicator of changing situation Atmosphere/Space High/Low when orbiting a planet

Tags: kerbal-space-program

When orbiting a celestial body, I would like to have a (vanilla/stock if possible) visual indicator of the transition of the position of my ship between altitude situations. In KSP there are several situations :

- Landed / Splashed
- Atmosphere Low / High
- In space Low / High

I know that a device is capable of showing in which *biome* I am but I want this position.

I also know that the wiki has this information but I would avoid doing alt-tab because I have the mouse on the "take measure" button and the transition may be quick...

I noticed several visual transitions :

- Landed / Splashed <-> Atmosphere or space : obvious
- Space Low -> Atmosphere High : music stops, wind sounds and atmosphere meter moving
- Atmosphere High -> Space Low : atmosphere meter at top left, Ap stops moving and music starts
- I noticed that sometimes the camera moves to another angle while descending

Visual indicators of Atmosphere Low <-> High and Space Low <-> High could help. Did you notice anything when transitionning these states ?

Comment: Installing [KER](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/17833-130-kerbal-engineer-redux-1130-2017-05-28/) would always be an option. Or [Science Alert](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/170748-131-sciencealert-191-experiment-availability-feedback-10feb18/).

Comment: `I noticed that sometimes the camera moves to another angle while descending` Just FYI, this is the boundary between orbital and surface mode. You'll see that the speed counter also switches from surface to orbit (or vice versa) at the same point. In orbit, the camera is oriented according to the orbital plane of the planet. In surface mode, the camera is oriented according to the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kerbal Engineer Redux is your most likely option. It provides tons upon tons of information not normally available, but you can switch it all off. In flight you normally get two HUD panels displaying several lines of data each. You can customize these too, and leave only 'situation'.

It's not perfect though - e.g. it doesn't recognize the microbiomes of KSP. Whether you're at VAB, launchpad, runway, you'll always be 'landed at Kerbin shores'.

Comment: I just installed KER and I'm like "why didn't I install this 400 hours ago?" and "Wow this is overcheated, I can directly know that my ship will not have enough dV to land on Ike". But the tweak to just show the situation is ok for me!

Comment: @Goufalite: I thought of two alternate approaches. 'Multispectral Imaging Platform' from DMagic Orbital Science displays current biome the way barometer displays pressure or thermometer - temperature. Alternatively, you can use ScanSat, which is a very interesting mod where you can generate maps (biome, altimetry) of planets by sending probes into orbit at the correct altitude, and it just starts filling the map with characteristics of the areas it flies over. With the biome map filled, you can see the icon of your craft over the map, along with layout of nearby biomes.

Comment: Both mods provide parts that can generate plenty of science though, so if you want vanilla experience just with the biome display, they may feel a little cheaty. One more very limited option is Indicator Lights. It adds indicators to a bunch of parts, including science parts; the lights blink green when there's new science to be collected by a given instrument. (also, steady green = there's data collected in the instrument, orange blink = you've already transmitted data from the current situation/biome, but can collect more by delivering it to Kerbin).